# Dynamic visualization of Graph[] on a webpage

Tags: export, graphs-and-networks, visualization, html

How can we embed a dynamic version of a `Graph` object on a web page, similar to the one showcased on the [networkx home page](http://networkx.github.io)?

This sort of dynamic visualization can be very useful for presentations, especially if more information could be shown than just the node names by tooltips.

Comment: Additional examples/answers are most welcome!

Comment: Since this can't even be done in *Mathematica*, I think an equally valid question would to be: how to implement the dynamic rearrangement of vertices in *Mathematica*, so that it can potentially be exported as a `CDF`. I'm not saying I would do that, though. I like the `SVG` + `JS` approach in your self-answer too.

Answer (score 17):

It seems networkx uses the D3 library and the example is based on [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).  We can adapt that code to work with Mathematica and generate JSON output from Mathematica.

1. Save the HTML from the linked page to `index.html`.  Change `miserables.json` in the source code to `graph.json`.
2. Generate JSON with Mathematica:

   ```
   g = RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[100, 1]]

   names = VertexList[g];
   groups = VertexDegree[g]; (* let's try degree-based colouring *)

   Export[
    "graph.json",
    {
     "nodes" -> 
      MapThread[{"name" -> #1, "group" -> #2} &, {names, groups}],
     "links" -> ({"source" -> #1 - 1, "target" -> #2 - 1, "value" -> 1} &) @@@ EdgeList[g]
    },
    "JSON"
   ]
   ```
3. Open `index.html`.

[image]

Note: If you're using Chrome, and clicking the above image takes you to an empty page, please click the shield in the right side of the address bar an authorize the script.

---

Additional worked examples welcome!  Please post an answer if you can show how to make something nice using this or similar tools.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov It's related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5416/strategies-for-interfacing-to-web-visualization-libraries-like-stanfords-data-d), but that question is very vague, so I wasn't very excited about it at that time.  But he's right: it would be nice to somehow make this kind of thing (interactive online graphics) more accessible for Mathematica users.  Personally I know nothing about D3 or JavaScript ... I wish I had more time to learn about them.

Comment: Ideally this type of thing would allow a time-sequence adjustment of the graph, where new vertices and edges could be seen 'growing'.  If you could expand your example to this it would be very cool.